# Proper use of Dependency Walker (depends.exe)

Tags: dependency-walker

I would like to check whether I am using Dependency Walker correctly. I make simple utility programs which I distribute for free, and I am just trying to ensure that they run correctly on other Windows machines. (I am small-scale; I don't have a separate clean machine for testing.)

1. List item
2. Configure Dependency Walker to ignore my PATH, though "Options" -> "Configure Module Search Order..." and then removing my path from the search order.
3. Open the executable in Dependency Walker.
4. Ignore these warnings, which seem inevitable "Warning: At least one delay-load dependency module was not found. Warning: At least one module has an unresolved import due to a missing export function in a delay-load dependent module."
5. If there are no further complaints, I assume my application should work on another machine.

Should that work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the Qt framework, there are at least two instances in which this will not work.

1. For a dynamically-linked Qt application, depends will not turn up the requirement for qwindows.dll to be in the platforms folder in the application directory.
2. For Qt applications using SQLite, depends does notice the requirement for qsqldriver.dll to be in the sqldrivers folder in the application directory.